# Error with cmake and jsonCPP static library target "jsoncpp_lib_static"

Tags: cmake, jsoncpp

When I try to use cmake on the jsonCPP i get the following error

```
CMake Error at lib_json/CMakeLists.txt:73 (INSTALL):
install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
"jsoncpp_lib_static"
```

I use the command from readme:

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_STATIC=ON -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_SHARED=OFF -G "Unix Makefiles" ../..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it looks as though you're pointing CMake to the CMakeLists.txt inside "/jsoncpp/src" rather than the root one at "/jsoncpp".

The root CMakeLists.txt defines the variable `ARCHIVE_INSTALL_DIR` at [this point](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L26-L27) and it's used in the "/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/CMakeLists.txt" at [this point](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/CMakeLists.txt#L76) to define the target's [`ARCHIVE DESTINATION`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/install.html#installing-targets).

Since you're skipping the root CMakeLists.txt, this variable never gets set.

The error message mentions the path `lib_json/CMakeLists.txt:73`, and this is relative to the "main" CMakeLists.txt - i.e. the one you pointed CMake to when you first executed it.  So CMake thinks the root is "/jsoncpp/src" instead of the real root.

Basically, to fix your error, clean out your build folder then rerun CMake to point to the "/jsoncpp" folder.

---

By the way, although the docs don't specifically mention it, I think the [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) is case-sensitive.  You should be doing `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.